# sed or awk script to correct link format

Tags: awk, sed

In our web documentation, a frequent mistake occurs when people leave out the closing " in an href link.

For example `<a href="https://example-site.com/about.html/ target="_blank">`

I have written a script which can be run on the markdown file to correct this:

`sed -i -e 's/ target=\"_blank\"/\"&/' docs.md`

This works and corrects the above to `<a href="https://example-site.com/about.html/" target="_blank">`

But it does not check for the absence of a `"` so if the link has been written correctly, it will add another one so it will become:

`<a href="https://example-site.com/about.html/"" target="_blank">`

It also assumes that the href link will always be followed by `target="_blank"`

So approaching it from the other way and checking that the block which follows `a href=` is always enclosed in `" "` is probably better.

If approaching it by checking that the content after href is enclosed in `" "` more examples of cases that would need to be dealt with are:

```
<a href="https://docs.appneta.com/api.html#getting-started-with-the-apm-api"
<a href="https://www.datadoghq.com/"
<a href="https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/users/#list-all-users"
<a href="https://help.emarsys.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000697445-About-Account-Owners"
<a href="https://guide.firstrain.com/api-v2/2017/04/28/authentication/"
```

What would be the best practice way to acheive this?

Comment: Does the part where you want to add the second `"` always end in `html/ ` or `/ ` as in  `https://example-site.com/about.html/ `?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: Edit your question and add several of the `a href=` lines so that there is a better example of what they might look like.

Comment: Will do when I'm back at my computer :)

Comment: @NasirRiley I have added some more examples to the description. While the answer from capt zipoc works, it would be very helpful to know how to approach it this way too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add " only if its doesnt have it, its like an if statement inside sed.
Does resolve the issue?

```
sed -iE '/" target=/b ;s/ target=/"&/' docs.md
```

Comment: Yes that works nicely!
Am I right in saying that the 'b' option jumps to the end of the script if that condition is met?

Comment: It jumps with its not met, its like a negate pattern.
You can find the whole thing at: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html#Branching-and-flow-control